# Is it just me or something is seriously wrong with new Python futures module on windows

Tags: python, future, executor, concurrent.futures

I am on windows XP and I have problems with new Python 3.2 futures module.
It seems I am unable to get `ProcessPoolExecutor` to work.
Session example:

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:29:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  

>>> from concurrent import futures  
>>> executor = futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()  
>>> def pio(x):  
...     print("I AM HERE")  
...     return True  
...  
>>> fut = executor.submit(pio, 5)  
>>> Process Process-1:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\Python32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 259, in _bootstrap  
  self.run()  
File "C:\Python32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run  
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)  
File "C:\Python32\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 133, in _process_worker  
  call_item = call_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.1)
File "C:\Python32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 131, in get
res = self._recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pio'

>>> fut.running()
True
```

It looks like something is wrong here to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to be aware that the [`concurrent.future`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html) module uses the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module (especially when you used the `ProcessPoolExecutor`), so some functionality will not work in the interactive interpreter, read more about this [here](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction).